# Pandas dataframe: how to find missing years in a timeseries?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a timestamp index and some 100,000 rows. Via

```
df['year'] = df.index.year
```

it is easy to create a new column which contains the year of each row. Now I want to find out which years are missing from my timeseries. So far, I understand that I can use groupby to obtain "something" which allows me to find the unique values. Thus,

```
grouped = df.groupby('year')
grouped.groups.keys()
```

will give me the years which are present in my dataset. I could now build a complete year vector with

```
pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='AS')
```

and through reindex I should then be able to find the missing years as those years which have NaN values.

However, this sounds awfully complicated for such seemingly simple task, and the grouped.groups operation actually takes quite a while; presumably, because it doesn't only look for unique keys, but also builds the index lists of rows that belong to each key, which is a feature that I don't need here.

Is there any way to obtain the unique elements of a dataframe column more directly/efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method would be to construct a series of the years of interest and then use `isin` to see the missing values:

```
In [89]:

year_s = pd.Series(np.arange(1993, 2015))
year_s
Out[89]:
0     1993
1     1994
2     1995
3     1996
4     1997
5     1998
6     1999
7     2000
8     2001
9     2002
10    2003
11    2004
12    2005
13    2006
14    2007
15    2008
16    2009
17    2010
18    2011
19    2012
20    2013
21    2014
dtype: int32

In [88]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1999, 2000, 2013]})
df
Out[88]:
   year
0  1999
1  2000
2  2013

In [91]:

year_s[~year_s.isin(df['year'])]
Out[91]:
0     1993
1     1994
2     1995
3     1996
4     1997
5     1998
8     2001
9     2002
10    2003
11    2004
12    2005
13    2006
14    2007
15    2008
16    2009
17    2010
18    2011
19    2012
21    2014
dtype: int32
```

So in your case you can generate the year series as above, then for your df you can get the years using:

```
df.index.year.unique()
```

which will be much quicker than performing a `groupby`.

Take care that the last value passed to `arange` is not included in the range

Comment: Brilliant! However, there is a slight mistake in the above: df.index.year returns a numpy array, not a pandas Series - hence, it doesn't have a unique method. Easily overcome with pd.Series(df.index.year).unique(), though.

Comment: @maschu yes that's true, you could just do `set(df.index.year)` would also work, if my answer answered your question then you can accept it, there will be an empty tick mark at the top left of my answer, you can also upvote

Comment: One follow-up question: while this works great for "year", I would like to do a similar thing for "yearmonth", i.e. a combination of YYYYMM values (so that each month of each year gets a specific label), As there is no attribute to directly extract "yearmonth" from index, what can I do in this case? Could I define a lambda function and apply this to the index values, for example?

Comment: How is this label going to look as what you're suggesting looks like a string? you should be able to do `import datetime as dt df.index.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y%m'))` I think should work

Comment: Found it: f=lambda x: x.year*100 + x.month ; df.index.map(f)  does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a list of missing years, you can first convert your Data Series to a list and simply build a list of missing years using a list comprehension:

```
years = df['year'].unique()
missing_years = [y for y in range(min(years), max(years)+1) if y not in years]
```